# How can I fix this System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array DMG

Tags: mysql, arrays, database

I am currently trying to fix this issue I am encountering is where the console is giving off errors for the array if anyone knows how to fix this.

If you can add me on skype mine is Bradley.dale4

The error is on line 247 which is.

```
                    if (Tamer.DigimonList[3] == null) qry.Add("mercenary3", null);
```

> Accepting a client: 151.226.122.217:60417 27
>   System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array.    at Digital_World.SqlDB.SaveTamer(Client client) in
>   C:\Users\Digimon Master\Dropbox\Digimon Master
>   Project\DMOFrosty'sPost\Server\ServerBuildingSection\DigitalWorld\Database
>   - Game.cs:line 247 A connection has closed.

**The Code**

```
        public static void SaveTamer(Client client)
    {
        int lastChar = -1, charId = -1;

        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection con = Connect())
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `acct` WHERE `accountId` = @acct", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acct", client.AccountID);
                using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
                    if (dr.HasRows && dr.Read())
                    {
                        lastChar = (int)dr["lastChar"];
                        if (lastChar != -1)
                        {
                            charId = (int)dr[string.Format("char{0}", lastChar + 1)];
                        }
                    }
            }

            if (lastChar != -1)
            {
                Character Tamer = client.Tamer;
                using (MySqlConnection con = Connect())
                {
                    Query qry = new Query(Query.QueryMode.UPDATE, "chars", new Tuple<string, object>("characterId", Tamer.CharacterId));
                    qry.Add("charModel", (int)Tamer.Model);
                    qry.Add("charName", Tamer.Name);
                    qry.Add("charLv", Tamer.Level);
                    qry.Add("experience", Tamer.EXP);
                    qry.Add("money", Tamer.Money);

                    qry.Add("partner", Tamer.DigimonList[0].DigiId);
                    if (Tamer.DigimonList[1] == null) qry.Add("mercenary1", null);
                    else qry.Add("mercenary1", Tamer.DigimonList[1].DigiId);
                    if (Tamer.DigimonList[2] == null) qry.Add("mercenary2", null);
                    else qry.Add("mercenary2", Tamer.DigimonList[2].DigiId);
                    if (Tamer.DigimonList.Length >= 3)
                    {
                        if (Tamer.DigimonList[3] == null) qry.Add("mercenary3", null);
                        else qry.Add("mercenary3", Tamer.DigimonList[3].DigiId);
                    }

                    qry.Add("map", Tamer.Location.Map);
                    qry.Add("x", Tamer.Location.PosX);
                    qry.Add("y", Tamer.Location.PosY);

                    qry.Add("inventoryLimit", Tamer.InventorySize);
                    qry.Add("storageLimit", Tamer.StorageSize);
                    qry.Add("archiveLimit", Tamer.ArchiveSize);

                    qry.Add("maxHP", Tamer.MaxHP);
                    qry.Add("maxDS", Tamer.MaxDS);
                    qry.Add("HP", Tamer.HP);
                    qry.Add("DS", Tamer.DS);
                    qry.Add("AT", Tamer.AT);
                    qry.Add("DE", Tamer.DE);
                    qry.Add("MS", Tamer.MS);
                    qry.Add("Fatigue", Tamer.Fatigue);

                    qry.Add("incubator", Tamer.Incubator);
                    qry.Add("incubatorLevel", Tamer.IncubatorLevel);

                    BinaryFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
                    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        f.Serialize(m, Tamer.ArchivedDigimon);
                        qry.Add("archive", m.ToArray());
                    }


                    //Trying to add cashvault and tempvault
                    qry.Add("inventory", Tamer.Inventory.Serialize());
                    qry.Add("equipment", Tamer.Equipment.Serialize());
                    qry.Add("storage", Tamer.Storage.Serialize());
                    qry.Add("quests", Tamer.Quests.Serialize());

                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = qry.GetCommand(con))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < Tamer.DigimonList.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (Tamer.DigimonList[i] != null)
                        SaveDigimon(Tamer.DigimonList[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward `Tamer.DigimonList` hasn't 4 itens you are trying to access an item that doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means there is no 4th (index starts with zero) item on your array. You should first check for the array count before performing your if condition.

**UPDATE**
Your condition should be "if your array count is equal to 4"

```
if (Tamer.DigimonList.Length == 4)
{
    if (Tamer.DigimonList[3] == null) qry.Add("mercenary3", null);
    else qry.Add("mercenary3", Tamer.DigimonList[3].DigiId);
}
```

Comment: Toni do you have skype if so can I add you for some help please?